# How do I find the Vendor ID of this RS-232 to USB-A 2.0 adapter?

Tags: usb, chipset, rs232, vendor-id

I need to programmatically allow permissions for this USB device via its vendor ID, but I don't know what its vendor ID is:

[image: Two ends of a cable. On top is the RS-232 end, which contains the chipset. Its casing is black and about twice as long as it is wide. Its markings are its serial number (7649163), and the text "Z-TEK CE". On bottom is the USB-A 2.0 end, which is standard size and marked with the USB symbol and a "+" sign.]

Does anyone know what the ID is, or how I can discover it?

Comment: How are we suppose to know?  Use `Device Manager`, on the machine it is connected to, in order to determine this information.  Use a machine that it can be connected to, in order to determine this information, a virtual machine is good for doing that.

Comment: When you plug the device in to a computer does `Device Manager` show the device?

Comment: Is that a Windows program? I don't have that luxury; I only have a Mac to work with :/

Comment: -3 without telling me why this is a bad question? Wow, this site is ruthless.

Answer (score 2):

To discover the vendor ID of any USB device, connect it to a computer and pull up a device diagnostics application. On Windows, this is Device Manager, and on Mac OS, this is System Information (Found as "System Report..." under About This Mac). Using this, you can discover that the ID is `0x0403`:

[image: Screenshot showing properties of the device, including the hilighted vendor ID "0x0403"]